# Is static checking performed for Contract.Ensures?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I cannot understand why static checker says that everything is ok for this method:

```
public static int GetNonNegativeValue()
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);

    return -1;
}
```

Static checking is on.

**Update:**

this is also ok.

```
var i = Doer.GetNonNegativeValue();
Contract.Assert(i < 0);
```

Comment: Good question. If nobody answers in this forum, try asking here instead (where the author of Code Contracts hangs out): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/threads

Comment: @MatthewWatson: They don't answer either. I tried contacting them via that forum and via mail. No reaction what-so-ever.

Comment: They can be a bit slow (sometimes taking over a week to answer!) I looked for your post in that forum so I could comment on it (to bump it) but I can't find it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Thanks for looking. It is actually a [bug report from two years ago](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/7df349d0-7cb1-4b5f-b6ec-c9e9e82ef546). It never got an answer from them and a few months ago I bumped it two times, adding new data. I could easily live with an answer after a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if this warning disappears when you activate "Infer Requires" in the settings of the static checker.

It will than infer `Contract.Requires(false)` ("CodeContracts: Suggested requires: Contract.Requires(false);") which will make this method "invalid", as it now can't be called without raising a contract exception. It looks like the contract checker doesn't verify the `Ensures` on such a method, because it wouldn't execute the `return` statement anyway.

BTW: Activating or deactivating "Show squigglies" doesn't change this behaviour in any way. I can only assume that the OP didn't just change this setting when he tested it.

Comment: That's a bit unfortunate because it turns a compile-time warning into a run-time error. :(

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Indeed. Infering `Contract.Requires(false)` seems like a pretty bad idea. I have disabled "Infer Requires" and "Infer Ensures" because the results are too unpredictable. I specify them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to re-check the following check box and then, rebuild the project:

> right click on the project -> Properties -> Code Contracts -> Show squigglies

Also, make sure that your solution's `Active Config` (or the specific project's `Build` configuration) matches the `Configuration` from the `Code Contracts` property page.

Comment: Thanks. It now works. But this does not follow from the documentation:

Show squigglies: Controls whether warnings emitted by the static checker appear as squigglies in the
source text. It is o by default as the squigglies can be overwhelming if lots of warnings are emitted.

So can it be treated as a bug?

Comment: I get that warning even without squigglies.

Comment: Even after you rebuild the project?

Comment: I don't get the warning, even WITH the squigglies! I'm using version 1.4.5.51019.0 on Visual Studio 2012 with Update 1.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: Sure. I am trying to figure out what setting actually influences this. Currently, I can't make that warning go away.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I also have Code Contracts version 1.4.5.51019.0, Visual Studio Premium 2012, Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1.

Comment: I got the same Code Contracts version but I am currently testing it in VS 2010.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Try unchecking "Infer Requires". Do you get that warning now?

Comment: I tried it in VS2010 too, and that also doesn't give me a warning. Very strange. (I've got everything cranked up to max, of course)

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: That's it! Unchecking "Infer Requires" makes it work. Sounds like a bug?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Not necessarily. See my answer for an attempt on an explanation.